# Regarding a method "cannot be resolved to a type" error

Tags: java, treenode, red-black-tree

I am trying to create null nodes at the bottom of a RBTree and want to instantiate EMPTY as an empty node.

this the line that has the error:

```
final private Node<E> EMPTY = new Empty();
```

And the empty class:

```
  private class Empty extends Node<E> {

    public Empty() {
        red = false;
    }
    public Node<E> add(E data) {
        count++;
        return new Node<E>(data);
    }
    public Node<E> getNode(E data) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know it has something to do with the constructor but I can't zero in on it. 
I have tried searching but most everything I come across on this site is related to android programming and/or some other language I'm not familiar with. I've tried the following:

(Node) casting the new Empty(); then realized it was obviously not that.

and working with the class seeing if public would work.

Aside from programming changes i've also tried the solutions offered here:

http://philip.yurchuk.com/software/eclipse-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error/

But to no success.

Sorry if this question is out of place, and thank you for your time!

complete code:

```
package data_structures;



public class RedBlackTree<E extends Comparable<E>> {

private Node<E> root;

private int count = 0;

final private Node<E> EMPTY = new Empty<E>();

public RedBlackTree() {
    root = EMPTY;
}

public void add(E data) {
    root = root.add(data);
    count++;
    root.red = false;
}


public boolean find(E data) {
    return root.getNode(data) != null;
}

private class Node<E> {
    public E data;

    public boolean red;
    public Node<E>   leftChild;
    public Node<E>   rightChild;

    /** Used by Empty */
    protected Node() {
        assert EMPTY == null;
    }

    /** Nodes always begin red */
    public Node(E k) {
        data  = k;
        red = true;
        leftChild  = (Node<E>) EMPTY;
        rightChild = (Node<E>) EMPTY;
    }

    private boolean isRed() {
        return red;
    }

    public int height(){
        return 0; //returns the counts binary left most bit position to determine the height.
    }

    public Node<E> add(E newData) {
        if(((Comparable<E>) newData).compareTo(data) == -1) {
            count++;
            leftChild = leftChild.add(newData);
            return leftChild;
        }
        if(((Comparable<E>) newData).compareTo(data) == +1){
            count++;
            rightChild = rightChild.add(newData);
            return rightChild;
        }
        if(((Comparable<E>) newData).compareTo(data) == 0){
            return this;
        }

        if (leftChild.isRed() && leftChild.leftChild.isRed()) {
            return balance(leftChild.leftChild, leftChild, this, 
                           leftChild.leftChild.rightChild, leftChild.rightChild);     

        } else if (leftChild.isRed() && leftChild.rightChild.isRed()) {
            return balance(leftChild, leftChild.rightChild, this, 
                           leftChild.rightChild.leftChild, leftChild.rightChild.rightChild); 

        } else if (rightChild.isRed() && rightChild.leftChild.isRed()) {
            return balance(this, rightChild.leftChild, rightChild,     
                           rightChild.leftChild.leftChild, rightChild.leftChild.rightChild); 

        } else if (rightChild.isRed() && rightChild.rightChild.isRed()) {
            return balance(this, rightChild, rightChild.rightChild,          
                           rightChild.leftChild, rightChild.rightChild.leftChild);     
        }

        return this;
    }


    /** Returns the node for this key, or null. */
    public Node<E> getNode(E newData) {
        if(((Comparable<E>) newData).compareTo(data) == -1){
            return leftChild.getNode(newData);  
        }
        if(((Comparable<E>) newData).compareTo(data) == +1){
            return rightChild.getNode(newData);
        }
        else{
            return this;
        }
    }
private class Empty<E> extends Node<E> {

    public Empty() {
        red = false;
    }
    public Node<E> add(E data) {
        count++;
        return new Node<E>(data);
    }
    public Node<E> getNode(E data) {
        return null;
    }
}

private Node<E> balance(Node<E> a, Node<E> b, Node<E> c, Node<E> d, Node<E> e) {

    a.rightChild = d;
    b.leftChild  = a;
    b.rightChild = c;
    c.leftChild  = e;
    a.red = false;
    b.red = true;
    c.red = false;
    return b;
}


}
```

}

Comment: I'm feeling invested now :) I deleted the old answer and put a new one.

Comment: I've copied your code, and updated my answer to something that compiles. There was the additional problem of where the Empty class was being defined.

Comment: Yes, i moved it out and voila no more errors! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write

```
Node<E> EMPTY = new Empty<E>();
```

because E is a generic type. You can only create an object with actual class, such as:

```
Node<String> EMPTY = new Empty<String>()
```

If you know what you are doing, you can do an ugly trick that should work with a warning

```
Node<E> EMPTY = new Empty();
```

Also, move the Empty class outside of Node.

Comment: That ugly trick still results in the same error. At the moment i'm looking for alternatives because I'm not sure what to do about this. I thought that repositioning the statement, but I don't think im able to put it anywhere else.